# How to change the icon color when button is active?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How to change the colors of icons when the active state of the button is changed? I'm using SVG icons since they are convenient. How can I modify the `SideBarButton` component to conditionally apply styles to the icon based on the active state. How can I achieve this ? Here are the SideBarButton and SideBar component codes (briefly)

```
const SideNavbar = ({ onSideNavBarClick }) => {
  const [activeButton, setActiveButton] = useState("Dashboard");

  const handleClick = (page) => {
    setActiveButton(page);
    onSideNavBarClick(page);
  };

  return (
    <SidebarWrapper>
      <SidebarBody>
        <UnorderedList>
          {makeButtons.map((btn, i) => (
            <SideBarButton
              key={i}
              onClick={() => handleClick(btn.title)}
              icon={btn.icon}
              title={btn.title}
              isActive={btn.title === activeButton}
            />
          ))}
        </UnorderedList>
      </SidebarBody>
    </SidebarWrapper>
  );
};

const makeButtons = [
  { icon: <img src={dashboard} alt="dashboard" />, title: "Dashboard" },
  { icon: <img src={patient} alt="patient" />, title: "Patients" },
  { icon: <img src={visits} alt="visits" />, title: "Appointments" },
  { icon: <img src={appointments} alt="appointments" />, title: "Visits" },
];
```

```
const SideBarButton = ({ onClick, icon, title, isActive }) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <ButtonSidebar onClick={onClick} className={isActive ? "active" : ""}>
        <Icon>{icon}</Icon>
        {title}
      </ButtonSidebar>
    </li>
  );
};
```

Comment: Have you written any CSS?

Comment: yh, but its not necessary for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple is create a array of button like this

```js
const makeButtons = [
  { 
    iconActiced: <img src={dashboardActive} alt="dashboardActive" />, title: "DashboardActive",
    iconDefault: <img src={dashboard} alt="dashboard" />, title: "Dashboard"
  },
];
```

```js
const SideBarButton = ({ onClick, iconActiced, iconDefault, title, isActive }) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <ButtonSidebar onClick={onClick} className={isActive ? "active" : ""}>
        <Icon>{isActive? iconActiced : iconDefault}</Icon>
        {title}
      </ButtonSidebar>
    </li>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NavLink` from `react-router-dom` which will help in routing and will provide a check for the active state as well:

Separate Icon for active and inactive state (replace with your icons):

```js
  const makeButtons = [
    { activeIcon: <DashboardActiveIcon />,icon: <DashboardIcon />, title: "Dashboard" },
    { activeIcon: <PatienActivetIcon/>,icon: <PatientIcon/>, title: "Patients" },
    { activeIcon: <AppointmentsActiveIcon />,icon: <AppointmentsIcon />, title: "Appointments" },
    { activeIcon: <VisitsActiveIcon />,icon: <VisitsIcon />, title: "Visits" },
  ];
```

```js
    <div>
      {makeButtons.map((btn, i) => (
        <NavLink
          to={"/your/route"}
          children={({ isActive }) => (
            <SideBarButton
              key={i}
              onClick={() => handleClick(btn.title)}
              icon={isActive ? btn.activeIcon : btn.icon}
              title={btn.title}
              isActive={btn.title === activeButton}
            />
          )}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
```

Comment: You don't need to add a new library to get this to work.

Comment: @Andy yes you are right, this can be done without libraries by having an active state. But I do feel that NavLinks do have an excellent usecase in these kind of scenarios.